# Tags added to my question I don't agree with

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, review, suggested-edits

I recently had tags added to one of my questions: [“Always Copy” solution content (DLLs) to executable directory root](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18985568/575530). The added tags were [reviewed by four people](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/913815) one who rejected the new tagging and three accepted.

Personally I don't agree. The question is about the VS build process not `.net` nor `c#` (I think).

What's the correct etiquette? Should I leave the new tags there as (1) it was kind of him to take the time to try and improve my question and (2) three knowledgeable reviewers accepted the new tags, or should I delete them?

Comment: One of them has now been banned from review.

Comment: I would assume that user is now auto-suspended from suggested edits considering they got 24 rejected edits in a matter of minutes.  Looks like they're gonna get smacked with a big serial-upvoting-reversal in the morning, too.

Comment: Usually stuff needs less tags, rarely more; and as a bonus of the meta effect I've added an answer.

Comment: all 4 reviewers are mad suspicious to me.

Comment: Two of them have now been banned from review.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I wouldn't assume much about the reviewers being knowledgeable. At least one of them's never met a review he didn't like. If your question has nothing to do with C# or .Net, remove the tags.